# Using Recaptcha v2 and Guest Entries plugin

Tags: craft2, plugin-guestentries, plugin-recaptcha

How can I prevent bots from sending tons of messages from a frontend form, it uses the Craft Guest Entries plugin. I'm using Recaptcha 2 but it only hides the submit button and it doesn't work using Craft 2.

All other solutions (antispam) that I check seems quite old...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with these, but here are some potential plugins you can look into for Craft 2 that use various anti-spam techniques:

https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/snaptcha

https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/sprout-invisible-captcha

https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/google-recaptcha

https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/spam-guard

Comment: I finally use Google reCaptcha plugin with Recaptcha Guest. Thanks for your response Brad!

https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/google-recaptcha

https://github.com/billythekid/recaptchaguest